# Can't find image while running on device, but can find it while running on simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm trying to load an UIImageView with an UIImage using [UIImage imageNamed:name]. The simulator works perfectly loading the image, but running the same code on an iPad terminates with an exception (because the UIImage ends up being nil). Why is this happening?
I added the images from XCode to 'Supporting Files/Images'.

Weird thing is that some files I added are being found ok, but these other images are not. The only difference between them is that I renamed the ones I cannot find from within XCode. I even tried removing and adding them back again, but no dice.

Case is not the issue, I already checked it.

This is on XCode 4.2 and iOS 5.

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the images exist in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of your target's Build Phases. Whatever you do, try cleaning your build folder first (option+shift+cmd+k). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Image names are case-sensitive on the device, but not on the simulator.

If your case is correct, reset the simulator.

http://www.jameskelso.com/post/9627437152/images-show-in-the-ios-simulator-but-not-on-a-device

Comment: This is not the issue, the image name is correctly set, I even tried copying and pasting the name of the image to prevent mistakes from my part. What's the point of resetting the simulator? it works ok there.

Comment: You note that you "could not find" some images in Xcode. What does this mean?